# Create Schema in oracle 10g express edition

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-xe

I have installed oracle 10g express edition and I did not find the option to 
   create schema..

Is there a option to create schema in oracle 10g express edition
   or else I have to install other oracle 10g..?

To create schema which oracle 10g
   I have to install... what?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to explicitly create schema, Oracle automatically creates a schema when you create a user (see **[`CREATE USER`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_8003.htm#i2065278)** documentation).

If you really want, you can use [**`CREATE SCHEMA`**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6013.htm) statement and issue it through Oracle Express web interface or from SQL prompt.

Answer (score 2):

The `CREATE SCHEMA` statement can include `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW`, and `GRANT` statements. To issue a `CREATE SCHEMA` statement, you must have the privileges necessary to issue the included statements.

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION oe
   CREATE TABLE new_product 
      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER) 
   CREATE VIEW new_product_view 
      AS SELECT color, quantity FROM new_product WHERE color = 'RED' 
   GRANT select ON new_product_view TO hr;
```

Answer (score 1):

As zendar said, creating a user automatically creates their schema (in Oracle these are pretty much the same concept).

When you create a Workspace in apex, it will ask you if you want to use an existing schema or create a new one - so that's another easy option you could use.