# How to create a database in oracle XE?

Tags: java, database, oracle

In oracle XE, there's a pre-installed database, about employees and departments and whatever, But i want to create a new database, I know I can do it in the command line, but I checked the database homepage and I only found creating tables, in the GUI, or the browser, I need to create my own database, and make a user who can access only this database and not the employees database

Comment: what version of oracle xe do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439265/create-schema-in-oracle-10g-express-edition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I think you mean "schema" and not "database". The installer program creates a database named XE, and inside that database is a schema named HR. To create additional schemas you could use any Oracle tool like SQL*Plus or Database Control, and all you do is create a new user account (because user=schema). However, what Oracle probably prefers over SQL*Plus is that you access the XE "Home Page" on your computer using the shortcut they put on your Win2K desktop, and then click on the Administration link

Read more here: http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1605421-creating-new-db-express-edition.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is steps in text mode with img-snapshots discarded...

'''Pre-requisites: should have admin privilege

'''This document covers only Microsoft Windows version of Oracle XE only

'''I've did this for Oracle XE 11g.... I hope it is same for all versions of Oracle XE....

1)  Install Oracle XE

2)  Make sure that you had noted down system password which you had given as part of the installation.

3)  After Installation start the Oracle XE service by clicking `Start Database`

4)  Open oracle web dashboard,- by clicking Getting Started page.

5)  Create new-user in the web dashboard.

```
a.  In the Getting Started web page, click on – “Application Express”

b.  Login as system user

c.  Now create new-user under Application Express, give the db-username,application-express-user-name as same for convenience.
```

6)  Once the db_user is created,  open sql_plus

7)  `connect sys as sysdba` and give `system` user password,

8)  Grant sysdba role to created-db

`grant sysdba to {database};`  for example `grant sysdba to pcbscheduler;`

9)  Now you are done with creating new database in XE (as it limited for.)

10) Try connecting from Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Somehow I had this difficulty that Oracle XE web dashboard didn't opened up. I tried pressing `F5` in a while, while trying on that specific port on which service was Up & Running. It didn't refrained. Else while I say I might've re-opened or so, that gave salvation in my try.

Answer (score 2):

In oracle xe I find it a bit weird; you have to create a user. Log in as that user and then you can create your database objects.

You can do it from the so called database homepage; if you want to really explore your options; after you created your user; you can install sql developer and connect with that; it works more intuitive for me.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following code in a batch file (ex. createOraDbWin.bat). Change the parameter values like app_name, ora_dir etc., Run the file with administrative privileges. The batch file creates a basic oracle database:

**Note** : May take much time (around 30 mins based on resource availability)

```
REM ASSUMPTIONS
rem oracle xe has been installed
rem oracle_home has been set
rem oracle_sid has been set
rem oracle service is running

REM SET PARAMETERS
set char_set =al32utf8
set nls_char_set =al16utf16

set ora_dir=d:\app\db\oracle
set version=11.2.0.0
set app_name=xyz
set db_name=%app_name%_db
set db_sid=%db_name%_sid
set db_ins=%db_name%_ins
set sys_passwd=x3y5z7
set system_passwd=1x4y9z

set max_log_files=32
set max_log_members=4
set max_log_history=100
set max_data_files=254
set max_instances=1

set version_dir=%ora_dir%\%version%
set db_dir=%version_dir%\%db_name%

set instl_temp_dir=%db_dir%\instl\script

set system_dir=%db_dir%\system
set user_dir=%db_dir%\user
set undo_dir=%db_dir%\undo
set sys_aux_dir=%db_dir%\sysaux
set temp_dir=%db_dir%\temp
set control_dir=%db_dir%\control

set pfile_dir=%db_dir%\pfile
set data_dir=%db_dir%\data
set index_dir=%db_dir%\index
set log_dir=%db_dir%\log
set backup_dir=%db_dir%\backup
set archive_dir=%db_dir%\archive

set data_dir=%db_dir%\data
set index_dir=%db_dir%\index
set log_dir=%db_dir%\log
set backup_dir=%db_dir%\backup
set archive_dir=%db_dir%\archive
set undo_dir=%db_dir%\undo
set default_dir=%db_dir%\default

set system_tbs=%db_name%_system_tbs
set user_tbs=%db_name%_user_tbs
set sys_aux_tbs=%db_name%_sys_aux_tbs
set temp_tbs=%db_name%_temp_tbs
set control_tbs=%db_name%_control_tbs

set data_tbs=%db_name%_data_tbs
set index_tbs=%db_name%_index_tbs
set log_tbs=%db_name%_log_tbs
set backup_tbs=%db_name%_backup_tbs
set archive_tbs=%db_name%_archive_tbs
set undo_tbs=%db_name%_undo_tbs
set default_tbs=%db_name%_default_tbs

set system_file=%system_dir%\%db_name%_system.dbf
set user_file=%user_dir%\%db_name%_user.dbf
set sys_aux_file=%sys_aux_dir%\%db_name%_sys_aux.dbf
set temp_file=%temp_dir%\%db_name%_temp.dbf
set control_file=%control_dir%\%db_name%_control.dbf

set data_file=%data_dir%\%db_name%_data.dbf
set index_file=%index_dir%\%db_name%_index.dbf
set backup_file=%backup_dir%\%db_name%_backup.dbf
set archive_file=%archive_dir%\%db_name%_archive.dbf
set undo_file=%undo_dir%\%db_name%_undo.dbf
set default_file=%default_dir%\%db_name%_default.dbf

set log1_file=%log_dir%\%db_name%_log1.log
set log2_file=%log_dir%\%db_name%_log2.log
set log3_file=%log_dir%\%db_name%_log3.log

set init_file=%pfile_dir%\init%db_sid%.ora
set db_create_file=%instl_temp_dir%\createdb.sql
set db_drop_file=dropdb.sql

set db_create_log=%instl_temp_dir%\db_create.log
set db_drop_log=db_drop.log

set oracle_sid=%db_sid%

REM WRITE DROP DATABASE SQL COMMANDS TO FILE
echo shutdown immediate;>%db_drop_file%
echo startup mount exclusive restrict;>>%db_drop_file%
echo drop database;>>%db_drop_file%

REM EXECUTE DROP DATABASE SQL COMMANDS FROM THE FILE    
rem sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" @"%db_drop_file%">%db_drop_log%

REM DELETE WINDOWS ORACLE SERVICE
rem oradim -delete -sid %db_sid%

REM CREATE DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
md %system_dir%
md %user_dir%
md %sys_aux_dir%
md %temp_dir%
md %control_dir%

md %pfile_dir%
md %data_dir%
md %index_dir%
md %log_dir%
md %backup_dir%
md %archive_dir%
md %undo_dir%
md %default_dir%
md %instl_temp_dir%

REM WRITE INIT FILE PARAMETERS TO INIT FILE
echo db_name='%db_name%'>%init_file%
echo memory_target=1024m>>%init_file%
echo processes=150>>%init_file%
echo sessions=20>>%init_file%
echo audit_file_dest=%user_dir%>>%init_file%
echo audit_trail ='db'>>%init_file%
echo db_block_size=8192>>%init_file%
echo db_domain=''>>%init_file%
echo diagnostic_dest=%db_dir%>>%init_file%
echo dispatchers='(protocol=tcp) (service=%app_name%xdb)'>>%init_file%
echo shared_servers=4>>%init_file%
echo open_cursors=300>>%init_file%
echo remote_login_passwordfile='exclusive'>>%init_file%
echo undo_management=auto>>%init_file%
echo undo_tablespace='%undo_tbs%'>>%init_file%
echo control_files = ("%control_dir%\control1.ora", "%control_dir%\control2.ora")>>%init_file%
echo job_queue_processes=4>>%init_file%
echo db_recovery_file_dest_size = 10g>>%init_file%
echo db_recovery_file_dest=%log_dir%>>%init_file%
echo compatible ='11.2.0'>>%init_file%

REM WRITE DB CREATE AND ITS RELATED SQL COMMAND TO FILE    
echo startup nomount pfile='%init_file%';>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo create database %db_name%>>%db_create_file%
echo user sys identified by %sys_passwd%>>%db_create_file%
echo user system identified by %system_passwd%>>%db_create_file%
echo logfile group 1 ('%log1_file%') size 100m,>>%db_create_file%
echo group 2 ('%log2_file%') size 100m,>>%db_create_file%
echo group 3 ('%log3_file%') size 100m>>%db_create_file%
echo maxlogfiles %max_log_files%>>%db_create_file%
echo maxlogmembers %max_log_members%>>%db_create_file%
echo maxloghistory %max_log_history%>>%db_create_file%
echo maxdatafiles %max_data_files%>>%db_create_file%
echo character set %char_set %>>%db_create_file%
echo national character set %nls_char_set %>>%db_create_file%
echo extent management local>>%db_create_file%
echo datafile '%system_file%' size 325m reuse>>%db_create_file%
echo sysaux datafile '%sys_aux_file%' size 325m reuse>>%db_create_file%
echo default tablespace %default_tbs%>>%db_create_file%
echo datafile '%default_file%'>>%db_create_file%
echo size 500m reuse autoextend on maxsize unlimited>>%db_create_file%
echo default temporary tablespace %temp_tbs%>>%db_create_file%
echo tempfile '%temp_file%'>>%db_create_file%
echo size 20m reuse>>%db_create_file%
echo undo tablespace %undo_tbs%>>%db_create_file%
echo datafile '%undo_file%'>>%db_create_file%
echo size 200m reuse autoextend on maxsize unlimited;>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo @?\rdbms\admin\catalog.sql>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo @?\rdbms\admin\catproc.sql>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo create spfile from pfile='%init_file%';>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo shutdown immediate;>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo startup;>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

echo show parameter spfile;>>%db_create_file%
echo.>>%db_create_file%

REM CREATE WINDOWS ORACLE SERVICE
oradim -new -sid %db_sid% -startmode auto

REM EXECUTE DB CREATE SQL COMMANDS FROM FILE
sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" @"%db_create_file%">%db_create_log%

pause
```

Welcome your corrections and improvements!